# Applications reporting "Illegal instruction" after upgrading glibc

Tags: linux, upgrade, glibc

**Background Info:**

Linux OS: Stripped down, minimalistic and very customized (no apt-get, yum, etc)

Linux Kernel: 2.6.19.1

Current glibc version: 2.3.6

Target glibc version: 2.6.1

**Issue:**

Attempting to install an ipk package provided by 3rd party which has a dependency on a glibc version >= 2.6 (current version is 2.3.6)

The 3rd party provided a different ipk package to upgrade glibc to 2.6.1. After executing the install of the package, all other applications that depend upon glibc report "libc.so.6: cannot handle TLS data"

Is anyone familiar with upgrading glibc on a customized Linux OS without using any sort of package manager for support?

My understanding is that glibc should be backwards compatible and upgrading it shouldn't cause issues with applications that had previously been working. Is this assumption incorrect?

I can post more information as it is requested.

**EDIT #1**

Added a `symlink` to the 3rd party `.ipk` for `glibc` to point `ld-linux.so.2` to `ld-2.6.1` and then attempted to re-install the package. This changed the original error (libc.so.6 cannot handle TLS data) to `Illegal instruction`

Comment: I *think* this means your `libc.so` and `ld.so` are out of sync.  Glibc *as a whole* is backward compatible with old binaries, but all of its own components must be upgraded in lockstep.

Comment: Please post the _complete, unedited_ output of: (1) `ls -ld {,/usr}/lib{,/*}/{ld,libc.}*`; (2) `cat /etc/ld.so.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf`; (3) `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` (yes, really, run the dynamic linker as if it were a regular program); (4) `/lib/libc.so.6` (yes, really, same thing for the primary "libc" shared object).  If either `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` or `/lib/libc.so.6` does not exist, tell us that.

Comment: It would also help to know exactly what distribution you are working from; I know you said it was "stripped down, minimalistic, and very customized", but you've got _some_ kind of package manager in there and it would help to know which one and what other quirks are relevant.  (I know I've _heard_ the acronym "IPK" before but I can't remember where it comes from.)

Comment: @zwol the problem is after I start seeing that error, commands like "ls" and "cat" no longer work.. I can provide you with the output of those commands prior to installing the glibc2.6 IPK, but I'm guessing that's not what you need

Comment: Do you have busybox installed? It ought to have ls, cat, etc.

Comment: @zwol IPKG is the name of the binary application used by the OS to install IPK files, short of that there really isn't any package manager on the system. The target device does not have internet access so we are update to pull packages from repos

Comment: Yes, I need after.  It would be even more helpful to see the answer for _both_ before and after.  Can you get your hands on a statically linked `busybox`, which will be immune?  Or can you mount the filesystem from within a working environment, e.g. a livecd?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I can tell you that after the error shows itself, running `ldconfg` produces `/usr/lib/libbusybox.so.1 is not a symbolic link`

Comment: [This ipkg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipkg)?

Comment: @zwol yes, thats the guy

Comment: @zwol RE: your `ld.so.2` comment, reviewing the files stored inside the IPK package, the new package installs `ld-linux.so.3`, but does not modify the original `ld-linux.so.2`, could this be where my issue is??

Comment: Yes, if it overwrites the existing `libc.so.6` but not the existing `ld-linux.so.2`, then after installation you will have the old dynamic linker trying to load the new libc, which isn't guaranteed to work.

Comment: Alright, great, looking into that now.. thank you

Comment: @zwol so now the issue is that I need to add the missing symlink to the IPK package, but can't figure out how to edit the `data.tar.gz` inside of the `.ipk` file to do so

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with that, I know nothing about ipkg.

Comment: @zwol got that handled, I believe, take a look at my edit in the question

Comment: OK, now you have a new problem.  Time to ask a new question :)

Comment: But Linux is not a OS, its just a kernel. It look like you are running Gnu on Linux. But you will have to be a bit more specific, as we can not read minds, that server went down last week, and we have not fixed it yet.